# Compute score for guess against given word

Tags: python

def compute_score(guess, position, word)

```
# word = 'castle'
# guess comes from previous function (e.g. 'ran')
# position = 0, 1, 2 --> where guess starts in relation to word
    # EG1 - 'ran' at pos=0 'ran', 'castle' --> a in rat and a in castle match
    # EG2 - 'ran' at pos=1 '_ran', 'castle'----> no matches
```

I want a way to to match each character from the guess to each character from the given word in the same position and give a score of +100
So for EG1 --> a in both words and same position but for EG2 --> a in both words but not same position. After the character has been checked it is put in a separate variable 'checked'

```
# Then I want to check just characters that are the same in each word
checked = 'a'
for c in guess and not in checked:
    if c in word:
    score = score + 20
```

I can't figure out how to do the first part --> check character is same AND in same position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you zip the two strings together, you get character pairs:

```
>>> zip("ABC", "aBCde")
[('A', 'a'), ('B', 'B'), ('C', 'C')]
```

Characters from the longer word are conveniently discarded. Now your problem is checking where the two characters in a pair are the same:

```
score = 0
for first, last in zip(word, guess):
    if first == last:
        score += 20
```

If you wanted to compute the score in a single expression you could use the fact that `True == 1` and `False == 0` and sum a comprehension:

```
score = 20*sum(first==last for (first, last) in zip(word, guess))
```

but this goes too far for some people's taste, and can be confusing to beginners.

Comment: Thanks! that was helpful. Also a little unrelated but how can I add 'underscores' to a word so the total word output is always 6 letters. So if the guess is 'an' at position 0 i want the output to be 'an____' or 'an' at position 1 I want the output to be '_an___'

Comment: `word += (6-len(word))*'_'` ought to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate()` to check for the index while iterating as it returns a list of index/character tuples, `enumerate('test')` would return `[(0, 't'), (1, 'e'), (2, 's'), (3, 't')]`. So you can do something like:

```
for i, c in enumerate(guess):
    if c not in checked:
        if word[i] == c:
            score += 20
        checked += c
```